# How to give 2 imported JS files visibility to each other in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In a React Native file:

```
import sjcl from './sjcl';
import './sha1x';
```

Functions in these files need access to each other. In particular, I'm trying to implement PBKDF2 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307634/4490400) example. The author notes that I need to include both files. How can I give the functions within these files visibility to each other without modifying the files?

Comment: What do you mean by visibility? Does `sha1x` expect `sjcl` to be a global variable? Without modifying the files, globals are the only way to go. Even if you _could_ modify the files, circular dependencies are a problem. Are you sure you can't shape this like a tree?

Comment: `sha1x` defines functions within the `sjcl` namespace, for example `sjcl.hash.sha1`. It doesn't know what `sjcl` is and crashes. I don't know if it expects `sjcl` to be a global variable.

Comment: If it says `sjcl.foo = bar`, and you don't want to put `import sjcl` on that file, the only possible way it can work is by making `sjcl` global (accessible from everywhere, always, like `String` or `Number`). I'm not sure how globals work on ReactNative (browser uses `window`, node uses `global`), Google must know